# maven-surefire-plugin: How do I get rid of individual columns in the xml report?

Tags: junit, playwright, maven-surefire-plugin, jira-zephyr, playwright-java

My goal is to have this tag in the XML generated by surefire:

```
<testcase name="NameMyTest">
```

For this, I used the line

```
@DisplayName("NameMyTest")
```

in my Playwright Java test case.

Unfortunately, something is appended to the test case name that I don't want. How do I find out where this attachment comes from? How can I avoid this?

Comment: First what is the problem? Why do you like to have that? And simple answer: not possible.

Comment: We want to enter test runs in Zephyr based on the test results. The test case name should be the reference to the corresponding Jira ticket.